# Yii2 - DetailView Search box

Tags: search, filter, widget, yii2, detailview

**I have this action inside ProdutosController. It renders view2 that has an itemview pointing to _view2 which has a DetailView to show products.**

```
public function actionView2()
{   
    $model = new Produtos();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Produtos::find(),
    'pagination' => false,
    ]);

    // get the posts in the current page
    $posts = $dataProvider->getModels();

    // render
    return $this->render('view2', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

**the view2**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ListView;
use yii\helpers\Url;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Atividades */

// $this->title = implode('', $cat);
?>
<div class="produtos-view2">
    <?php
    //use kartik\social\FacebookPlugin;
    //echo FacebookPlugin::widget(['type'=>FacebookPlugin::SHARE, 'settings' `=> []]);`
    ?>
</div>

<?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_view2',
]); ?>

<br/><br/>
```

**and the _view2 that as DetailView inside:**

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'options' => ['class' => 'detail1-galeria-view2'],
    'attributes' => [
        // cria um array com a fotografia, em que carrega a path no campo fieldName da bd
        [
            'attribute'=>'',
            //'value'=>$model->foto,
            'value'=>Html::a(Html::img(Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->getBaseUrl() . "/" .$model->foto, ['width'=>'192', 'height' => "256"]), $model->foto),
            'format' => 'raw',
        ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'value'=>$model->nome,
        ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'value'=>$model->categoria,
        ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'value'=>$model->descricao,
        ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'value'=>$model->valor.' '.'€',
        ],
        // info
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'format' => 'raw',
        'value'=> Html::a(Yii::t('app','Comprar'), Url::toRoute(['contacto/create2'])),
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

In another project i was able to make a search box in _view2 by render _search.php inside it and by modifying the ProdutosSearch model. But this was achieved with a GridView that accepts $dataprovider and $searchModel directly inside the widget.

**Now in my new project, i'm trying hard to make a search input box to filter what the DetailView shows (it shows the foto, name, category, etc... of products) but cannot do it because the detail view doesn't accept $dataProvider data.**

How can i solve this and make a products gallery with search box using a **DetailView**.

**EDIT**

Controller action:

```
public function actionMySearchFunction()
{   
    $model = new Produtos();
    $searchModel = new CategoriasSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Produtos::find(),
    'pagination' => false,
    ]);

    // get the posts in the current page
    $posts = $dataProvider->getModels();

    // render
    return $this->render('view2', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

**MySearchFunction.php**

```
<?php
public function MySearchFunction()

{
$post = Yii::$app->request->post(); 

if (!empty($post)){

    $postParam1 = $post['categoria']; // get the value ffrom the filter field submitted) 

    $query = ProdutosSearch::find()->where(['categoria' =>  $postParam1]);

    $dataProvider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=15;

    return $this->render('view2', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);

}
```

}
?>

**VIEW2**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => Url::to(['/produtos/my-search-function']),
    'method' => 'get',
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-inline form-group form-group-sm col-xs-12'],
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => "{input}",
    ],
]); ?>
</div>
<?php echo var_dump(Url::to(['/produtos/my-search-function'])); ?>

<!--<nobr><?= $form->field($model, 'nome')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Nome']) ?>-->

<nobr>
    <?= $form->field($searchModel, 'categoria')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Categorias::find()->all(), 'categoria','categoria'), ['prompt'=>Yii::t('yii', 'Escolha a categoria...')])  ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Pesquisar'), ['class' => 'btn btn-warning']) ?>
</nobr>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

<div class="user-view">

    <?= ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'itemView' => '_view2',
    ]); ?>

    <br/><br/>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add the fields you need in an action from section inside the view,
the search button submit the value to an action you use for search and the you can redirect the resulto to the controller you need.

In the action Form you can set the target controller/action. In this way pressing the submit botton the value in the submitted the the controller/action you have eg:

```
public function actionMySearchFunction()
{

    $post = Yii::$app->request->post(); 

    if (!empty($post)){

        $postParam1 = $post['name_field_Filter1']; // get the value ffrom the filter field submitted) 

        $postParam2 = $post['name_field_Filter2'];

        $query = YourModel::find()->where(['field1' =>  $postParam1, 'field2' =>  $postParam2]);

        $dataProvider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=15;

        return $this->render('your_view', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);

    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to create the form action and render, and the search button. But how to submit the value to an action to search?

My submit button is like:
<?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Pesquisar'), ['class' => 'btn btn-warning']) ?>

Comment: I created MySearchFunction.php inside Produtos Folder along with the other views there. I made a action with Url pointing to Produtos/MySearchFunction inside the form, but have te following error:

exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request: produtos/MySearchFunction'

Comment: The Url in the navigator shows:
http://localhost:8888/beladona/web/index.php?r=produtos%2FMySearchFunction&CategoriasSearch%5Bcategoria%5D=Funerais

Comment: You must create actionMySearchFunction and not MySearchFunction in the Produtos controllers

Comment: Remeber that call an action is do in this wat produtos/my-search-function  no camelCase non start with uppercase...

Comment: renamed MySearchFunction.php to actionMySearchFunction.php and still got the NOT FOUND 404 error.

Comment: Here is my form action: <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action' => Url::to(['produtos/actionMySearchFunction']),
        'method' => 'get',
        'options' => ['class' => 'form-inline form-group form-group-sm col-xs-12'],
        'fieldConfig' => [
            'template' => "{input}",
        ],
    ]); ?>

Comment: Try Url::to(['produtos/my-search-function'])

Comment: try with  Url::to(['/produtos/my-search-function'])  (add the slash '/' at the begin otherwise try to echo/var_dump(Url::to(['/produtos/my-search-function'])) and check the result path. eventually show me the result uopdatting the question...

Comment: Result path: string(55) "/beladona/web/index.php?r=produtos%2Fmy-search-function"

Comment: Check if the controller/action is called inserting  var:dump('test'); return; and the beginning of  actionMySearchFunction code, could be you try to render an view does not exist;

Comment: Please edit your question and add the controller/action (MySearch....) and the activeForm where you submit the data...

Comment: Edit is uploaded. The 404 error is solved, but it doesn't filter the detailview acording to the query. It does nothing, just flickers the screen.

Comment: You use post or get method for submit .. ? if you read post you should set method post,  method get if you red get... check please

Comment: Just for curiosity which was causing the 404 error?

Comment: The 404 error was fault of mine that did not include the correct action in the controller. I substitute get for POST but it doesnt do the search.

Comment: Well,  try check what's inside $post  with var_dump($post) before the if in action ..  could be a problem related to the activeForm id

Comment: Cannot <?php echo var_dump($post); ?> in MySeearchForm.php because this view doesnt show up. What shows up is view2.php that loads the all page. Maybe i should give up and start a fresh try with a new aproach?

Comment: I asked to add var_dump in controller (not in view)  inside the actionMySearchFunction just after the $post = = Yii::$app->request->post();

Answer (score 0):

first add search box on that page :

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="student-form">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($searchModel, 'nome') ?>

    <?= $form->field($searchModel, 'categoria') ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Apply', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

then in model prepare a filter method.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['nome', 'string'],
        ['categoria', 'string'],
    ];
}

public function scenarios()
{
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}

public function search($params)
{
    $query = Produtos::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $query]);

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'nome', $this->nome])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'categoria', $this->categoria]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Comment: I already tried that way, but for some reason with a DetailView widget it doesn't work.